# Install linux 2.6.33 kernel

Tags: kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linux kernel 2.6 installation on blank computer](https://superuser.com/questions/113724/linux-kernel-2-6-installation-on-blank-computer)

I'm new to Linux. I have just downloaded the linux kernel 2.6.33 form http://www.kernel.org
I want to use that on my computer which doesn't install any operation system. How do i?

Comment: duplicate (practice makes perfect): http://superuser.com/questions/113724/linux-kernel-2-6-installation-on-blank-computer

Answer (score 4):

Usually you really don't want to install the kernel manually, but instead want to install a [Linux distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) (which includes the kernel and tons of other necessary and useful stuff).

A special kind of "distribution" is [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) which is probably the closes you get to "installing the kernel". It's basically an instruction on how to manually install a complete Linux system from scratch. My suggestion is to only do that, if you really want to learn how it works underneath or if you have a *very, very* specific need for it.

Answer (score 3):

you'd better start by getting a linux distro. the kernel alone won't do much good for you.

try ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntu.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** want - read [Linux from scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) book. But, it isn't very simple.